# comparig two table or query and table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have one table like this:

```
cp_store  name    qty
"Cp1"   "pesto" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "jivara"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Nocciola"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Parfait"   "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Crema" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Crema" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Malaga"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "mango" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Lampone"   "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Caramello_Salato"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "albicocca" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
```

and I use this query

```
SELECT cp_store, nome, SUM(CAST(qta AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS total 
FROM tb_store 
WHERE  data_out is null 
GROUP BY cp_store, nome 
ORDER BY cp_store, nome
```

to obtain this:

```
cp_store  name    qty
 "Cp1"  "Cioccolato"    "6.0"
 "Cp1"  "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
 "Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "3.0"
 "nice1"  "Cioccolato_al_rum" "2.0"
 "nice1"  "Bacio_Siculo"  "3.0"
.
.
.
```

but I would like to compare the result name with this table:

```
id name        presence cp_store 
1 "Cioccolato"  "1" "All" 
2 "Bacio_Siculo"    "1" "All" 
3 "Ricotta_Limone"  "1" "All" 
4 "Cioccolato_al_rum"   "1" "All" 
5 "Pistacchio"  "1" "All" 
6 "Nocciola"    "1" "nice1" 
7 "Mascarpone"  "1" "Cp1"
8 "Limone"  "0" "Cp1"
```

.
.
.

and if the **name** is present and the **cp_store** is equal at ALL , but was not found in the result of the first query the final result qty of this is 0, like this:

```
cp_store    name                 qty
 "Cp1"      "Cioccolato"        "6.0"
 "Cp1"      "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
 "Cp1"      "Bacio_Siculo"      "3.0"
 "nice1"    "Cioccolato_al_rum" "2.0"
 "nice1"    "Bacio_Siculo"      "3.0"
 "All"      "Pistacchio"        "0"
 "All"      "Limone"            "0"
```

how is possible?

Comment: Which one? MySQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the subquery, and use `0` as the default value for `qty` if it's not found.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.cp_store, 'All') AS cp_store, t1.name, COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS qty
FROM tb_products AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cp_store, nome, SUM(CAST(qta AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS total 
    FROM tb_store 
    WHERE  data_out is null 
    GROUP BY cp_store, nome 
    ORDER BY cp_store, nome) AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.nome
```

Comment: ok, I changed a little bit:
SELECT t2.cp_store, t1.nome, COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS qty
FROM tb_product AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cp_store, nome, SUM(CAST(qta AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS total 
 FROM tb_store 
 WHERE  data_out is null GROUP BY cp_store, nome ORDER BY cp_store, nome)
 AS t2 ON t1.nome = t2.nome order by qty desc

but in the first column when the result is NULL is possible to sobstitute with "ALL"?

Comment: `COALESCE(t2.cp_store, 'ALL')`

Comment: If you understand what `COALESCE` does, it should be obvious.